# Virtualized list in pure JS

Tags: javascript, chat, virtualization

I am looking for virtualized list library, created to work in vanilla JS, that supports variable height of row/item in list. Sticky items (like position: sticky) support is also welcome.

There must be option for adding new items on fly also - prepending and appending.

I need it for chat log representation - like messanger / whatsapp etc.

Are there some battle-tested libraries that meet these requirements?